# Is there a word for this concept?

Tags: words, hebrew, yiddish

I recently learned the Korean word [han](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_(cultural)), which, according to Wikipedia, "denotes a collective feeling of oppression and isolation in the face of insurmountable odds (the overcoming of which is beyond the nation's capabilities on its own). It connotes aspects of lament and unavenged injustice." Supposedly this is something unique to Korean culture, but of course as a Jew I identify with it very strongly and find it intimately familiar. So my question is:

> The concept of *Han* exists in Jewish culture. Is there a Jewish (i.e., Hebrew or Yiddish) word for it?

## A few examples of Han in Jewish culture

1. The שפך את-אפיך passage from the Haggadah
2. This passage from the Amidah (quoted from chabad.org):

> Let there be no hope for informers, and may all the heretics and all the wicked instantly perish; may all the enemies of Your people be speedily extirpated; and may You swiftly uproot, break, crush and subdue the reign of wickedness speedily in our days. Blessed are You L-rd, who crushes enemies and subdues the wicked.

3. The centrality of the churban and the two exiles
4. The Yiddish saying ס'איז שווער צו זיין א ייד
5. *The Fixer*, by Bernard Malamud, which is the story of a Jew tormented by anti-Semites for three hundred pages.

## Defense of the on-topic-ness of the question

The question encompasses Jewish liturgy and theology (see examples 1--3 above). Thus Judaism. Thus on-topic.

Comment: Why do you assume it exists in "Jewish culture" just because you feel it?

Comment: @Danno See my edits above.

Comment: But I don't see the examples as indicative of the feeling you describe. Faith in  heavenly justice and a sadness over suffering are simply extensions of emunah that there is a complete  and divine plan.

Comment: Maybe, but the examples I cited cover a broader territory than that. E.g., in _The Fixer_ there is no justice and no divine plan; there's just suffering. That Yiddish proverb is similar. And those two tefillos I cited aren't just about faith in heavenly justice about the attendant emotions. They're very angry, very frustrated. It's not just about faith in heavenly justice but _yearning_ for revenge.

Comment: Note that we are supposed to have the attitude that everything is up to Hashem to set up and that we cannotdo anything on our own. I am not sure that we could have the emotion that you describe without also feeling "kochi veotzem yadi" and lacking emunah in Hashem.

Comment: I disagree. It's _because_ we can't do anything on our own that we have to plead for vengeance in those tefillos I cited.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term [*Golus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_diaspora) covers what you are looking for. I do not mean the literal translation, but rather the sentimental feeling the word gives, and its application even by those that live in Israel.

Comment: _Golus_ covers the sadness, I think, but not the resentment and anger.

Comment: @crmdgn resentment and anger against who?

Comment: @crmdgn I disagree. When a chossid gets put in prison or the city board is closing his shul, he is likely to say *oy vey tatte, mir zennen in gulis, mir zennen in gulis* in anger and resentment over the injustice being done to him.